# Please explain the following piece of code. I'm a beginner so please help me understand

Tags: c, function-pointers, typedef

```
typedef long (*GuiFunc) (int, int, int, unsigned short*, long, long);
```

Please help me understand the above line of code

Comment: Where did you get that?

Comment: It's a pointer to a funtion taking 6 parameters and returning a long int.

Comment: Following up on hackks' question, you seem to be attempting to utilize something which is above your current level of understanding. Consider taking a look at a good C tutorial.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys for the prompt input. So I understand that the typedef name is GuiFunc. 
So whenever I need to define a function pointer, I will simply write: 

GuiFunc functionPointer = &somefunction;

I understand now. Thanks for the help. You guys are great.

Comment: Why are you calling this a duplicate? The OP has seen that line of code and he does not understand it, hence he cannot know it is about function pointers, don't you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typedef long (*GuiFunc) (int, int, int, unsigned short*, long, long);
```

Defines new type `GuiFunc`.that can declare  a function pointer which takes 6 parameters `int, int, int, unsigned short*, long, long` and `returns long`.

Assume you have a function like this

```
long foo(int, int, int, unsigned short*, long, long)
{

}
```

if you declare

```
Guifunc callback; //declare a varaible of type Guifunc
callback=foo;
```

then you can call foo function like this `long x=callback(6parameters);`

Answer (score 1):

you are defining a new type here.

The new type here is a function pointer.

the function pointer has 6 input arguments

Answer (score 1):

You define a type `GuiFunc` which is a *pointer* (that's that `(*GuiFunc)` construct) to a function (the stuff in parentheses) which takes 3 `ints`, a pointer to `unsigned short`, two `longs` and returns a long.

Comment: I know from text book knowledge that :
    typedef int dog;
    dog counter;
    counter = 5;

that's how it goes. Now does the line of code mean that I am using a function pointer in place of long?

Comment: No, that's a special syntax for typedefs for function pointers. C language is not very regular in its declarations.